# How to configure log out in iPhone 4.0

Tags: ios, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate

How to configure log out in iPhone 4.0 as it does not call [`applicationWillTerminate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) method in 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support multi-tasking you are supposed to implement the `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method in your app delegate for saving state, as well as in `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` to support devices that do not have multi-tasking support or pre 4.0 iOS.

But you can also force iOS to use the "old" behavior, that is to not support multi-tasking and always call `applicationWillTerminate:`. To do that, you need to edit your Info.plist and add the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` with a boolean value YES.